# How to Handle Multiple Object Insertion in Entity Framework?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-4.1, edmx

I have a List to save in my database "Challan" table.
Currently I use the **foreach loop to insert objects into the database and with each iteration I use the Context.SaveChanges() method.**
Inside the loop I also call **ManageStock()** method to update stock of products, which resides in other class file.

I want to save all List with stock management at the same time, meaning if power failure or other errors occurr between insertion then saved record will be rolled back. And if the whole transaction has no errors then only it will save with all entries.

How can I achieve this in Entity Framework?

Comment: You're calling `SaveChanges` on _every_ insert? That goes against the whole _Unit of Work_ pattern. Keep your save for when all changes have been queued up. You'll notice better performance this way as well.

Comment: Thanks Brad For Your Quick Response,But How Can I Do That For My Stock Management Function Which Is Reside In Another Class?

Comment: I don't have any code to advise against so it's hard to give you an absolute answer. However, you should probably be referencing that context in any other methods that make use of it instead of relying on committing and retrieving changes between each work unit.

Comment: Thanks Brad For Your Advice,Can I Pass Object of EntityModel To My ManageStock Function()?I Put My Code Snippet Here for better understanding.

Comment: Foreach(Challan_ComplexType obj in lst){FACHLN obj = SetObject(obj);objDatabase.AddToFACHLNs(obj);objDatabase.SaveChanges();objCommon.ManageStock(obj.Tot_Quantity);   }

Comment: Just call `objDatabase.SaveChanges()` *after* the foreach loop and not inside of it.